# Google Apps Script : How to use the copyTo function with a local string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I came across a problem with my code in Google Apps Script for Sheets. I want to get cell values from 3 different cells, concatenate them in a single string variable, and copy this string variable into a cell of my spredsheet, using the copyto function.

The problem is that Google Apps Script doesn't recognize copyto as a function, because it doesn't work with local string variables (it works fine with other function variables, such as getrange or else). Here is the part of my code that doesn't work :

```js
  var prog = f1.getRange("A3");
  var jour = f1.getRange("B1");
  var heure = f1.getRange("B2");
  var texte = prog+" - "+jour+" à "+heure;

  heure.copyTo(f2.getRange(1,2))
```

f1 is properly defined.

Where do I get this wrong ? Is there a workaround for this ?

Cheers

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You want to copy `texte` to `f2.getRange(1,2)`, but in the code you are providing, you are using `heure`. (`copyTo` cannot work with a string, since it's a method of the `Range` class instead) And yet you say it doesn't work (without specifying what error, if any, you are getting). In order to write `texte` to your desired cell, use `f2.getRange(1,2).setValue(texte);`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You say that f1 is properly defined and yet this example is complete and works as well.

```
function copy2test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh.getRange('A1').copyTo(sh2.getRange('A2'));
}
```

Your example is incomplete because I cannot copy it and put it into my code editor and reproduce the same result as you get.  So you haven't met the requirement for reproducibility.  In my own mind I simply look at your example and assume that you don't know what you're talking about when you say it's defined properly.

You placed it in a snippet. So just run it: It returns an error with the following:

{
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: f1 is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 12,
"colno": 22
}

So you snippet result and I both agree.  It's not defined properly.

Comment: Actually I only pasted the part of my code I was having trouble with. But now that you mention it - I see the problem of not meeting the requirement for reproductibility. I managed to find a workaround of my own anyway ! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across the same problem as I was, here is my solution. Because copyTo doesn't work with a string variable such as I had (or at least I don't know how to make it work), I used a different method which produces the same result.

Instead of `heure.copyTo(f2.getRange(1,2))`
I used `f2.getRange(1,2).setValue([texte]);`
which does what I wanted and work with a string variable.

Comment: I guess credit should go to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685829/google-apps-script-how-to-use-the-copyto-function-with-a-local-string#comment119640560_67685829), in which I explained what the problem and the solution was. Also, consider providing `texte` without an array (`[texte]`) to `setValue`. This method accepts a string, so while a single element array can be accepted now, this could stop working without notice.